# Difference between mongodb driver and mongodb for node.js

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb documentation has two separate sections, one is the mongodb manual https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/ and the other is documentation for mongodb node driver https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/

However, both have node.js code examples, while my project only uses mongodb driver, and the version for mongodb is different than mongodb driver. Does this mean I can use whatever I see on the mongodb manual page as if it was a part of mongodb driver? What is the difference in versions? If one of them is a subset of the other, how do I know which versions are compatible?

Comment: I didn't get the question. But the key points:1. The first link describes common details about server and shell (i didn't see anything about node there).2. The second describes the node driver. 3. `version for mongodb is different than mongodb driver` -the driver and server release versions never match. Any modern driver version can work with any modern server version. There 2 exceptions: 1. new features- if the let's say the latest server introduced a new feature, only latest driver can work with it and similar. 2. Latest drivers can deprecate and remove supporting for really ancient servers

Comment: example with code (node and other languages) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: and? The server documentation says that you can use this functionality via the driver

Comment: it does, but doesn't mention anything about versions, hence the question - it does however answer my first question.

You've mentioned that any modern driver works with any modern server, so that means there shouldn't be any version conflicts - thank you for the explanation